# If JazzSm is installed in a virtual directory, DWC installation fails on Win 10

Tags: workload-scheduler

Dynamic Workload Console installation fails on Windows 10 if JazzSm is installed in a virtual directory (i.e. C:\Program Files). A pop up appears asking for the credential.

Answer (score 0):

to circumvent the problem, insert the JazzSm credentials or install both Dynamic Workload Console and JazzSm in a non-virtual directory.